# Can I make a visual block the current search term?

Tags: vim

Lets say there is some block of text that I want to search for in the file. Is there a way to make a visual-block selection of that text and then make it the current search term? That way I'd be able to do s//replacementText/g without typing the whole thing on the left side of the substitute command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to forgive me, I can't remember where I found this, but it works wonders. Just add to your `.vimrc`. Use your typical `*` and `#` after visually selecting:

```
" Search for selected text, forwards or backwards.
vnoremap <silent> * :<C-U>
  \let old_reg=getreg('"')<Bar>let old_regtype=getregtype('"')<CR>
  \gvy/<C-R><C-R>=substitute(
  \escape(@", '/\.*$^~['), '\_s\+', '\\_s\\+', 'g')<CR><CR>
  \gV:call setreg('"', old_reg, old_regtype)<CR>
vnoremap <silent> # :<C-U>
  \let old_reg=getreg('"')<Bar>let old_regtype=getregtype('"')<CR>
  \gvy?<C-R><C-R>=substitute(
  \escape(@", '?\.*$^~['), '\_s\+', '\\_s\\+', 'g')<CR><CR>
  \gV:call setreg('"', old_reg, old_regtype)<CR>
```

The real advantage here is that this escapes any special chars, versus just pasting into search command. It's also less keystrokes, which maximizes the vimness of your task.

Answer (score 4):

Make a visual block and yank it to the unnamed register `""`: with a visual block selected, type `y` to yank. Begin the search with `/` - or `:s/` and type `Ctrl-r` then `"` to insert the contents of the unnamed register as the search term.

This won't make the block the current search, but it's nearly as easy.

`Ctrl-r` can be used anywhere in the command-line, so you can also use this e.g. to fill in the substitution or replacement text, or in insert mode.

Comment: Great, reliable, go-to method, particularly if you're on a remote machine or environment that you can't load up a custom .vimrc easily.